# How can I get information about the users network when he tries to authenticate towards my IIS?

Tags: security, authentication, iis-7, passwords

I want users, when they are in the workplace (e.g. on the LAN), to authenticate themselves with their regular username and password. Auto-login is disabled.

However - logging in from outside the LAN should trigger a 2-level authentication (like SMS, mail or similar). How can we get information about the users network when they try to log in to the application from outside the LAN?

NB - it does not matter if you have AD user and pwd. If you are on the outside you have to trigger the 2 level auth.

NB2 - we do not want any client-side scripts running, so this must be something coming with the initial request

Technology: IIS 7, ISA 2006, .Net 4, MS Sql 2008 server.

Question also asked here: https://serverfault.com/questions/354183/what-2-level-authentication-mechanism-is-available-that-can-differentiate-if-the

Information why ISA server remove the information I need: http://www.redline-software.com/eng/support/articles/isaserver/security/x-forwarded-isa-track.php

Comment: -1 for not being a real question??? Without leaving any comments or anything?

Comment: +1 from me. It's clear and reasonable: how do I determine if a user is on the LAN and vary authentication based on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's reasonable, don't expose your web server to anything outside of your LAN -- require VPN access.

If that isn't reasonable, you should be able to use the `REMOTE_ADDR` variable to determine the source of the request. Whitelist your LAN as single-factor and require everything else to be multi-factor. Depending on the scenario, the [server variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) will be similar to either

```
Context.Request.ServerVariables ["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

or

```
Request.UserHostAddress()
```

If you have a proxy in the way, make the proxy tag the originating IP source in the headers and read the request headers to determine the external IP.

Comment: Thank you! We cannot require VPN access as there are people (read: customers) on the outside that need to be able to access the system. There is (of course) an ISA server in the way. We have a staging environment we'll try this out to see how it works.

Comment: @sonstabo Could you (business wise -- easily done technically) require that staff logins are in a VPN, but leave customers unaffected?

Comment: not really. That would increase the cost and introduce (yet) another element in an existing complex infrastructure. I definetly see your point, but I am afraid that it is not an option, at least for now. But I'll keep it in mind for possible new requirements in the future.

Comment: This was a great idea until we tested with the ISA server. It stripped away every piece of information and the client ended up coming from the ISA server itself (or that is the information received @IIS) even with "originating client" flag set.

Comment: @sonstabo It will always appear to come from the ISA if you're looking at the IP data. You need to have a originating IP header in the HTTP request and inspect that.

Comment: yes, we figured that out as well. Cannot say if I disagree with MS on that decision since forwarding the IP isn't the RFC standard... or if I disagree with MS not forwarding the IP as it is the de facto standard in the business (http://www.redline-software.com/eng/support/articles/isaserver/security/x-forwarded-isa-track.php).

Comment: We concluded on creating a mechanism that will be issue an encrypted secret to the client when on the LAN. If this secret is unavailable from the client machine he is de facto outside the LAN. We see that it has some holes, but we will focus on a tough encryption and short lifetime to reduce the risks.